# Does running the Visual Studio Installer to install extra features remove previously installed features?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, windows-installer, installation

I installed Visual Studio and .Net Development features, but missed the Apache Cordova option. I now wish to install it. I have opened the installer again, and this time it says `Modify`. It had the previously installed features selected; I've deselected them because I do not wish to reinstall them again (I want to keep them as is). I have now only selected the Mobile Development With Javascript option (Cordova).

Is this going to uninstall the previously selected .Net features? If thats the case I will reselect them for re-installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the risk and went ahead with the modification. The installer only installs the selected features; it does not uninstall anything that is deselected but installed on the machine. I Hope this helps someone in this same situation.

Comment: Hi, what's your VS version and which workload or individual components did you uncheck? Refer to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/modify-visual-studio?view=vs-2017#modify-workloads,from the Workloads/individual components screen, select or deselect the workloads that you want to install or uninstall.

Comment: The question wasn't necessarily about not being sure what to install or uninstall. I just wanted to know if deselecting already installed items will uninstall them. Seem otherwise.

Comment: Hi, when we modify the VS installer and uncheck the installed items, it should uninstall them, I also tried to test it in my side and it be removed since I uncheck it.

Comment: @SaraLiu-MSFT Nope, it didn't uninstall mine. Was your installer labelled `Modify` or `Install`? Also was that a first install, or a subsequent install? If its the first then its not uninstalling, its just not doing anything. Same as when modifying, its doesn't uninstall the selected items. Thats what happened in my case at least.

Comment: For the initial installation, uncheck it means not to install. For the modify, if we uncheck the installed features, those features will be uninstall. It seems your test result is different with mine. So that why I want to confirm your VS version and workloads, then I will try to reproduce this issue in my side, check if it is a issue or not, thanks for your understanding.

Comment: @SaraLiu-MSFT Visual Studio 2017 Version 15.9.5.  Are you using the VS installer file? Interesting that we had different results ey

Comment: Hi, thanks for your detail information. Which workloads or individual component did you uncheck, and how/where did you check it not be uninstall after the modify installation? I made a test in the VS enterprise 2017 15.9.5, uncheck the workload 'python development' to modify, after the installation complete, then open VS and go to File-New-project-Installed, there is no python project types, they are be removed since I uncheck the python development workload. Meanwhile, do you have any other VS 2017 version on the same computer?

Comment: @SaraLiu-MSFT I've just confirmed my answer again. I went into the installer to install `Entity Framework 6 Tools`. That is all that I selected. Prior to this screen I had selected `Modify`. The installer only installed Entity Framework 6 tools. Everything else was left as is